# ContentControl Name as CommandParameter in Interaction Triggers in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, triggers

I have several buttons on a Content Control, and i want to know when each of them is pressed and released. From my research i found that the only way to do this is using Interaction Triggers, but correct me if there is an easier way.

Since i have 10+ buttons, and assigning PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp takes up to 8 lines per button, i defined a custom button that i can reuse like this in my UserControl.Resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="ButtonWTriggers" x:Shared="False">
        <inter:Interaction.Triggers>
            <inter:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <inter:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ButtonDownCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}"/>
            </inter:EventTrigger>
            <inter:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                <inter:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ButtonUpCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}"/>
            </inter:EventTrigger>
        </inter:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>    
</UserControl.Resources>

<ContentControl Name="testbutton" Content="{StaticResource ButtonWTriggers}"/>
```

And then i'm using it with:

```
<ContentControl Name="testbutton" Content="{StaticResource ButtonWTriggers}"/>
```

Since the resource is used several times, and i want to know exactly which button was pressed, i was thinking of using the `ContentControl Name=<NAME HERE>` as parameter for the command. I tried getting that name with `CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}"` but its not working. The actions for Press and Release are executed but the parameter is empty, probably because it's trying to get the name property in the button instead of the content control right?

Can someone help me get the Name of the ContentControl as Parameter for the Trigger Command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with your problem is to use the `RelativeSource.AncestorLevel` property to skip the `Button` itself:

```
<inter:InvokeCommandAction (...) CommantParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl, AncestorLevel=2}}" />
```

But I consider that highly unreliable since it'll stop working if for example the `Button`'s template contains a `ContentControl` (relative source would then resolve to `Button` itself again).

Much more reliable solution in my opinion is to bind `Button.Tag` property to the name of its ancestor, and then bind the `InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter` to that property instead:

```
<Button (...) Tag="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}">
    (...)
    <inter:InvokeCommandAction (...) CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" />
    (...)
</Button>
```

If however you already use `Button.Tag` property for something else, an intermediate solution would be to make use of the `Button.Parent` property:

```
<inter:InvokeCommandAction (...) CommantParameter="{Binding Parent.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" />
```

Note though that despite these methods are equivalent in your particular case, they're not equivalent in general, so pick wisely.

Comment: Its actually the first time i use the Tag property, so the second solution works well. Thank you!